# How i can detect My Graphic Card is CUDA or Ray Tracing in C#

Tags: c#

I am building a program that displays system information. And i need help to detect Graphic Card is CUDA or Ray Tracing. Thank you.

Comment: Use ManagerObjectSearcher : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8d81b8a3-c101-4b47-8274-dd743fa41ec4/get-devices-by-connection-as-in-device-manager?forum=csharpgeneral&force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng AFAIK, you cannot determine whether the system has a graphics device with support for CUDA or RayTracing via `ManagerObjectSearcher`.

Comment: I found more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667666/how-get-gpu-information-in-c

Comment: @alelom : Microsoft has a standard hardware interface the contain limited info and generic drives use the limited interface.  The hardware interface also includes vendor optional data which can only be accessed with vendor drivers (not generic drivers).  Support for CUDA may be available depending on the vendor and part.

Comment: Exactly; in other words, `ManagerObjectSearcher` is not a solution in all cases; furthermore, I never saw a successful application of it in finding whether CUDA is supported or, even less likely, Ray Tracing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can install System.Management nuget package and use managerObjectSearcher, like that:

C#:

```
static private void GetGraphicsCardInfo()
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_VideoController");
        ManagementObjectCollection items = searcher.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject resultCollection in searcher.Get())
            foreach (var property in resultCollection.Properties)
                Console.WriteLine($"[{property.Name}] - {property.Value} ({property.Type})");
    }
```

I think in your case be worth pay attention on VideoArchitecture property

[image]

Comment: How i can detect with This property Graphics Card has CUDA or no? This property is just number.

Comment: details about the properties can be found on msdn https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-videocontroller
https://powershell.one/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_videocontroller

Comment: This answer doesn't respond to the original question, which is to determine whether there is a graphics device with CUDA. AFAIK, you cannot obtain that information via `ManagerObjectSearcher`.